# Is there a secure transaction plugin for mobile games?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, windows-mobile

I am trying to make an in game economy where users can buy items in game and sell items they loot and have the money instantly deposited/withdrawn from there bank account with no limitations on micro-transactions. is there a plug in api which i can easily add to my mobile games??

Comment: on iOS all in app transactions must go through apple (via in app purchases).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the apple in-app purchasing guidelines. In particular you will want to read the bit about "An online game that allows the player to purchase virtual property"